# How to check mysql table field type in nodejs before inserting data

Tags: mysql, node.js

i am trying to insert some data into mysql table using nodejs. These data are dynamic , so before inserting how can i check the field type , i am facing issue when trying to insert 'date ' to date field type.

```
         for(var i = 0; i < insertdata.length; i++){
                                var post=[];
                                post  = insertdata[i];

                                var querydd = connection.query('INSERT INTO '+ req.body.table_name + ' SET ?', post, function(err, result) {

                                });

                            }
```

data trying to insert is as follows

```
      { category: 'sd',
          book_id: '56353',
          author_book: 'Sir Alex Ferguson',
           book_title: 'Leading',
          price: '11',
          publication: 'abc',
          publication_date: '12-10-2015' }
     { category: 'df',
       book_id: '73638',
       author_book: 'Eric Smith',
        book_title: 'How Google Works',
        price: '110',
        publication: 'abcdd',
        publication_date: '17-10-2016' }
       { category: 'ffs',
           book_id: '37364',
          author_book: 'William Shakespeare',
           book_title: 'The Merchant of Venice',
           price: '200',
           publication: 'sgre',
           publication_date: '2017-10-2016' }
```

Answer (score 0):

1. `12-10-2015` is a `string`. Try convert it to `Date` by `new Date(yyyy-mm-dd)` before insert.
2. Typically `for (var i = 0; i < insertdata.length; i++)` is a not correct code to insert multiply rows. You don't control execute flow, e.g. what do if some query fail? Read `async` or `promises`.
3. `('INSERT INTO '+ req.body.table_name + ' SET ?', post` is a dangerous code (see SQL-injection). You must be careful with input data. The better way is use placeholder like a `insert into mytable set field = ?, field2 = ?, data, ...`
4. You can read db-field property from [metadata tables](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/information-schema.html).